# Open Facebook page via Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

How can I open Facebook page using insalled Facebook app? Exactly page, not profile, because fb://profile works fine.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/page_id")));
```

Seems like fb://page isn't working, because it's just opens feed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*fb://page/{id}* is the way to go:

```
final String url = "fb://page/" + facebookID
Intent facebookAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
facebookAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(facebookAppIntent);
```

Are you sure you are using the **ID number** of your Facebook page and NOT the **username**?

What I mean is that if, for example, you want to open the Facebook page of Facebook itself (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/facebook) you have to use:

```
fb://page/20531316728
```

Since *20531316728* is the **ID** of the Facebook page (while *facebook* is the **username**).

If you don't know the ID of your Facebook page, you can retrieve it opening:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{username}
```

Comment: its so boring you need to get the id, which mean, in some apps, if requires another api call, and lag in time

Comment: Thank you! If you want to open "note"/"notes" page, you can replace "page "with "note" like this: final String url = "fb://note/" + facebookNoteID;

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure That You are Using the page id of your page **correctly**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                .parse("fb://page/YOUR PAGE ID"));
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u should use

> https://www.facebook.com/
>   instead of fb://page/ or fb://profile or something.
>   I hope it's helpful!