# How to open a specific facebook page from my app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm developing a **material design** app.

I want to open **my app's facebook page** when user clicks on the '*like on facebook*' text (layout) in my app.

I've managed to open the **facebook app** but I am unable to figure out how can I open my page directly!

Here's what I've done so far:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutFacebookContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.facebook_container);
        linearLayoutFacebookContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent facebookIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                        if (facebookIntent != null) {
                            // We found the activity now start the activity
                            facebookIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/HumaneHelper/"));
                            startActivity(facebookIntent);
                        } else {
                            // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
                            facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            facebookIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/HumaneHelper/"));
                            startActivity(facebookIntent);
                        }
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        });
```

Please let me know.

I'm a beginner, please cooperate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this answer might help you .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10213314/2900893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*fb://page/{id}* is the way to go:

```
final String url = "fb://page/" + facebookID
Intent facebookAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
facebookAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(facebookAppIntent);
```

Are you sure you are using the **ID number** of your Facebook page and NOT the **username**?

What I mean is that if, for example, you want to open the Facebook page of Facebook itself (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/facebook) you have to use:

```
fb://page/20531316728
```

Since *20531316728* is the **ID** of the Facebook page (while *facebook* is the **username**).

If you don't know the ID of your Facebook page, you can retrieve it opening:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{username}
```

Courtesy: [Open Facebook page via Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890827/open-facebook-page-via-facebook-app/21135450#21135450)

Comment: What is the ID here:

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "Eef40vN5d+6"
   }
}`

Comment: Facebook Access Token for Pages, Please refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8235011/2691974

Comment: May be this could also help you https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=378910098941520